# AWS Environments VPN issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc

We have a limited # of VPN connections in house that is limiting how many environments we can have on AWS. We want to add more environments for other teams but there aren't enough VPN connections available and networking would need to add capacity to make these connections.

Is there a way on AWS to create new environments from a cloudformation template without needing a VPN connection into the building? I've seen a few tools like DirectConnect but am not sure if that would be a solution to this issue.

We're wanting to establish just one VPN connection to AWS (like a VPC that had multiple other VPCs under it?).

Has anyone done this before? Could use some guidance!

Comment: I think you must have to consult with the top vpn provider like purevpn, expres or any other....

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the solution is to build one single "Transit VPC", which has peering set up with all of your other VPCs. You connect to this one transit VPC once via VPN, and then can set routing and firewall rules according to where you want to allow or restrict traffic.

In fact, AWS itself blogged about this [just a couple of months ago](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-solution-transit-vpc/).